# Kendo Grid with DropdownList

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, grid, kendo-ui

Hi I'm using Kendo grid with dropdownlist, I followed the demo in http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/foreignkeycolumn.html 
but Im recieving this error "DataBinding: 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem' does not contain a property with the name 'Id'".

Could anyone help me to make my code work without error?

here is my viewModel :

```
public class AccountingViewModel

{
    private string _code = string.Empty;

    private string _description = string.Empty;

    public int Id
    {
        get;set;
    }

    public string Code
    {
        get { return _code; }
        set { _code = value; }
    }

    public string Description
    {
        get { return _description; }
        set { _description = value; }
    }

    public int MajorCategoryId
    {
        get;set;
    }

    public SelectList MajorCategories
    {
        get;set;
    }
}
```

Here is my Controller :

```
 public ActionResult Index()

    {
        var majorCategory = new SelectList(new[]
                                      {
                                          new {Id="1",Name="Category1"},
                                          new{Id="2",Name="Category2"},
                                          new{Id="3",Name="Category3"},
                                      },
                        "Id", "Name", 1);

        ViewData["majorCategories"] = majorCategory;

        return View(accountingService.GetAllAccountings());

    }
```

Here is my Index View:

```
 @model IEnumerable < PPMS.Model.ViewModels.AccountingViewModel >
 < br/ >

< div class="k-grid" >

 @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
.Name("grid")
.Columns(columns =>
       {
             columns.Bound(p => p.Code);
             columns.Bound(p => p.Description).Width(150);
              columns.ForeignKey(p => p.MajorCategoryId, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["majorCategories"], "Id", "Name")
                           .Title("MajorCategory").Width(150);

         columns.Command(command => command.Destroy()).Width(110);
                   })
      .ToolBar(toolBar =>
                   {
                       toolBar.Save();
                       toolBar.Create();
                   })
      .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
      .Filterable()
      .Groupable()
      .Pageable()     
      .Scrollable()
      .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:430px;" })    
      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                    .Ajax()
                    .Batch(true)
                    .PageSize(20)
                    .ServerOperation(false)
                    .Events(events => events.Error("errorHandler"))
                     .Model(model =>
                                    {
                                        model.Id(p => p.Id);
                                        model.Field(p => p.Id).Editable(false);
                                   model.Field(p => p.MajorCategoryId).DefaultValue(1);       
                                               })

                       .Create(create => create.Action("Create", "Accounting"))
                       .Read(read => read.Action("Index", "Accounting"))  
                       .Update(update => update.Action("Edit", "Accounting")) 
                       .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("Delete", "Accounting"))
       )
      )
</div>
<br/>


<script type="text/javascript">


function errorHandler(e) {
    if (e.errors) {
        var message = "Errors:\n";
        $.each(e.errors, function (key, value) {
            if ('errors' in value) {
                $.each(value.errors, function () {
                    message += this + "\n";
                });
            }
        });
        alert(message);
    }
 }


</script>
```

I have updated my view into and is now binding the selectlist the problem now its displaying textbox inside the grid instead of a dropdownlist.. here is my updated Index view:

Here is my Index View:

```
 @model IEnumerable < PPMS.Model.ViewModels.AccountingViewModel >
 < br/ >

< div class="k-grid" >

 @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
.Name("grid")
.Columns(columns =>
       {
             columns.Bound(p => p.Code);
             columns.Bound(p => p.Description).Width(150);
              columns.ForeignKey(p => p.MajorCategoryId, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["majorCategories"], "Value", "Text")
                           .Title("MajorCategory").Width(150);

         columns.Command(command => command.Destroy()).Width(110);
                   })
      .ToolBar(toolBar =>
                   {
                       toolBar.Save();
                       toolBar.Create();
                   })
      .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
      .Filterable()
      .Groupable()
      .Pageable()     
      .Scrollable()
      .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:430px;" })    
      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                    .Ajax()
                    .Batch(true)
                    .PageSize(20)
                    .ServerOperation(false)
                    .Events(events => events.Error("errorHandler"))
                     .Model(model =>
                                    {
                                        model.Id(p => p.Id);
                                        model.Field(p => p.Id).Editable(false);
                                   model.Field(p => p.MajorCategoryId).DefaultValue(1);       
                                               })

                       .Create(create => create.Action("Create", "Accounting"))
                       .Read(read => read.Action("Index", "Accounting"))  
                       .Update(update => update.Action("Edit", "Accounting")) 
                       .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("Delete", "Accounting"))
       )
      )
</div>
<br/>


<script type="text/javascript">


function errorHandler(e) {
    if (e.errors) {
        var message = "Errors:\n";
        $.each(e.errors, function (key, value) {
            if ('errors' in value) {
                $.each(value.errors, function () {
                    message += this + "\n";
                });
            }
        });
        alert(message);
    }
 }


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The foreign dropdown list should contain items which have a "value" and "text" property ?

Like:

> var categories = [{
>                       "value": 1,
>                       "text": "Beverages"
>                   },{
>                       "value": 2,
>                       "text": "Condiments"
>                   }
>                   }];